# In R, how to return the observation groups, not the number of observations?

Tags: r, grouping

I have a large data frame that I am attempting to run a `for loop`, but need to get all the different observations first.  The process that I am currently trying to approach is this:

1. Create a list/vector/data frame of the observation
2. Use each observation in a `for loop`

Here is how I tackled it:

Generate some data:

```
x <- gl(12,5)
```

The result I am looking for is a list of all the different observations:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

I could create a `data frame`, then drop the number columns like this:

```
list <- data.frame(table(x))

list[,2] <- NULL

print(list)
```

From this list/vector/dataframe, I would run through the `for loop` like so:

```
for (i in list) print(i)
```

There must be a more efficient way to get the list for the `for loop`.  Can someone suggest one?

Comment: `plyr` is perfect for this task. You have just described the split-apply strategy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several options include:

```
R> unique(x)
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
R> levels(x)
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12"
R> as.numeric(levels(x))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

The `levels()` ones are most logical and appropriate if you want the groupings.

Now whether you really want this is another question. See `?split` which can split up a data frame on the basis of a factor (which you can `lapply()` over), or `?aggregate` among others. There is also the **plyr** package which seems very popular for this sort of thing.